# Multiline textbox - "Code blocks are not supported in this context"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a multiline (> 50 lines) textbox containing plain text. I want to add either a session variable to the text in this box.  In asp I would have done it by putting in <% %> code blocks but in .net I am getting the following error: "Code blocks are not supported in this context". I assume therefore that this would need doing in code behind.

Is there a quicker way than putting all the text from the textbox in a string in code-behind and then adding the variable on like this?  I would like to keep the text in my aspx page if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about your codebehind does something like:

```
myTextbox.Text += Session ["mySessionVariable"];
```

*after* you've filled the textbox.

Incidentally, you don't have to

> 'put all the text from the textbox in
>   a string in codebehind'

as the .Net framework exposes all the front-end controls as codebehind objects automatically.

EDIT:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Rows="15" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="70" Text='<%# Session["var1"] %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

This will work for binding just the session variable to the control. Don't forget to call

```
Page.DataBind();
```

after you've set your Session variables. Probably in `Page_Load`.

This will allow the binding such as it is, to occur. This won't work if you want to mix up static markup text with dynamic variables. For that, you'll need to get busy in the code-behind.

HTH.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really explain it fully...the variable is within the text, i.e. text here, variable, more text - and it all ideally needs to be in the same textbox.

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Rows="15" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="70">Text here, variable here: <% Session("something") %></asp:TextBox> The above gives me the error.

Comment: @ajguk - pls. see Edit above.

Comment: Thanks - the variable will be mixed in the static text so code-behind it is.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `<%=Session["MySessionKey"] %>` ?

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Rows="15" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="70">Text here, variable here: <% Session("something") %></asp:TextBox>

The above gives me the error.